# Create a new Dataframe using ArcPy in 10.1

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a new empty dataframe in ArcMap 10.1 using Arcpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, map layout elements cannot be created in arcpy -- they must be pre-authored, after which you can use [arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/) to move them, resize them, set properties, etc.

In 10.1 they added cloning for [text](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000m000000) and [graphic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000) elements, but this does not apply to [data frames](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/), so it must be pre-authored.

For more info see:

- [Guidelines for arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Guidelines_for_arcpy_mapping/00s30000006s000000/)
- [What's new for automating map workflows in ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//016w00000022000000)

Comment: This is what i thought, but I was hoping someone had some more insight on a workaround or something I had missed in the data model.  Thanks!

Comment: One neat technique I saw at the Esri conference was pre-authoring as many data frames as you may ever need OUTSIDE of the page space, and then simply moving them back ONTO the page space as needed.